# Changing a property of :after element for small devices

Tags: jquery, css, media-queries

I want to change the height of the underline link effect to adapt to different viewports , here is my css.

```
a,a:visited,a:hover,a:active{
    -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
    backface-visibility:hidden;
    position:relative;
    transition:0.5s color ease;
    text-decoration:none;
}
a.after:after{
    content: "";
    transition:0.5s all ease;
    -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
    backface-visibility:hidden;
    position:absolute;
}
a.after:after{
    bottom:-0.03em;
    height:0.15em;
    width:0;
    background:#d73444;
}
a:after{
    left:50.3%;
    -webkit-transform:translateX(-50%);
    transform:translateX(-50%);
}
a.after:hover:after{
    width: 100%;
}
```

So i want to change a.after:after (height) for different resolutions somehow , is there any way to do that with css or jquery , is there any library that i can use to make it work ?

Answer (score 1):

[CSS3 media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) are used for this exact purpose.

For example, since you want to change the `height` in `a.after:after` you can do something like:

```
@media (max-width: 400px){
    a.after:after {
      height: 1em;
   }
}
```

What this will do is it will replace any current styles you already have for that element with the styles inside of the brackets so long as the width of the viewport is not greater than 400px. Once it is greater than 400px those styles will no longer be applied.